# Error in MAXFLOW-MINCUT code

Tags: c++, max-flow

I have written a Max-Flow class using the edmonds-karp implementation. The code seems to work correctly when I try to get the value of the max flow. I submitted the code on SPOJ [TotalFlow](http://www.spoj.com/problems/MTOTALF/) so I believe the implementation is correct.

But I am trying to get the Min-Cut from the residual graph. This has led to some errors. Any help would be useful.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

class EdmondsKarp
{
private:
    vector<vector<int>> graph;
    vector<vector<int>> rGraph;
    vector<vector<int>> capacities;
    vector<int> parent;
    vector<bool> visited;
    int source, sink;
    int flow;
public:
    EdmondsKarp(vector<vector<int>> graph, vector<vector<int>> capacities, int source, int sink)
    {
        this->graph = graph;
        this->capacities = capacities;
        this->rGraph = capacities;
        this->source = source;
        this->sink = sink;
        parent.resize(rGraph.size());
        visited.resize(rGraph.size());
        makeFlow();
    }
    bool bfs()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < visited.size(); i++)
        {
            visited[i] = false;
        }

        queue<int> q;
        visited[source] = true;
        parent[source] = -1;
        q.push(source);
        int qf, v;
        while (!q.empty())
        {
            qf = q.front();
            q.pop();
            for (int i = 0; i < graph[qf].size(); i++)
            {
                v = graph[qf][i];
                if (!visited[v] && rGraph[qf][v] > 0)
                {
                    q.push(v);
                    parent[v] = qf;
                    visited[v] = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return visited[sink];
    }

    int makeFlow()
    {
        int INF = 9 + 1e9;
        flow = 0;
        int u, v, path_flow;
        while (bfs())
        {
            path_flow = INF;
            for (v = sink; v != source; v = parent[v])
            {
                u = parent[v];
                path_flow = min(path_flow, rGraph[u][v]);
            }

            for (v = sink; v != source; v = parent[v])
            {
                u = parent[v];
                rGraph[u][v] -= path_flow;
                rGraph[v][u] += path_flow;
            }
            flow += path_flow;
        }
        return 1;
    }

    int getFlow()
    {
        return flow;
    }

    vector<vector<int>> getFlowGraph()
    {
        vector<vector<int>> flowGraph(capacities.size(), vector<int>(capacities.size(), 0));
        for (int i = 0; i < capacities.size(); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < capacities[i].size(); j++)
            {
                if (capacities[i][j] > 0)
                {
                    flowGraph[i][j] = capacities[i][j] - rGraph[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
        return flowGraph;
    }

    vector<int> getMinCut()
    {
        vector<int> cut;
        bfs();
        int cutsize = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < visited.size(); i++)
        {
            if (visited[i])
            {
                cut.push_back(i);
                for (int j = 0; j < graph[i].size(); j++)
                {
                    if (!visited[graph[i][j]])
                    {
                        cutsize += capacities[i][graph[i][j]];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        cout << cutsize << endl;
        return cut;
    }
};
```

My main function is the following

```
int main()
{
    vector<vector<int>> graph(300, vector<int>(0)), capacities(300, vector<int>(300, 0));
    int m, w;
    char x, y;
    cin >> m;
    while (m--)
    {
        cin >> x >> y >> w;
        graph[x].push_back(y);
        capacities[x][y] += w;
        graph[y].push_back(x);
        capacities[y][x] += w;
    }
    EdmondsKarp edk(graph, capacities, 'A', 'Z');
    edk.getMinCut();
}
```

Comment: "led to some errors" is a little generic, maybe you should elaborate

Comment: Ok changing the statement. I meant that the value of cutsize was wrong. It is not giving me the correct answer.

Comment: For what input? what was the value you received and what did you expect? Please add these to your question, and try to find the simplest example that reproduces this problem

Comment: Unfortunately SPOJ does not give out the test data. So I am unable to find the correct test case. I have tried generating 5-6 small test cases but have been unable to find a discrepancy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to fix the getMinCut function. Unfortunately I have not figured out what was wrong in the original code. I am nor running through all possible edge combinations and adding the appropriate ones to the cut.

```
vector<int> getMinCut()
{
  vector<int> cut;
  bfs();
  for (int i = 0; i < visited.size(); i++)
  {
    if(visited[i])
    {
      cut.push_back(i);
    }
  }
  int cutsize = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < graph.size(); i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; j < graph.size(); j++)
    {
      if(visited[i] && !visited[j])
      {
        cutsize += capacities[i][j];
      }
    }
  }
  cout << cutsize << endl;
  return cut;
}
```